# How to add an overlay to Google Maps API in Xcode

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, google-maps, maps

I was wondering how I can add lines to a Google Maps API for Xcode.

You can see here that Google added a purple dotted line along a road which can be clicked on for further details.

[image: Google added a purple dotted line along a road which can be clicked on for further details]

Is this possible in Xcode and how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The [Maps SDK for IOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/intro) allows you to add [Polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes#polylines) to draw lines on a Google map which you can then customize to make it have a similar look to the line shown in the image you've posted.

Hope this helps you get started!